# Google Maps API and costs. Beginner question

Tags: api, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

First of all: i am a total beginner, especially with Google Cloud Platform.

I am building a Real Estate website that includes flats that are imported into the CMS via APIs. The flats are uploaded and managed from my client in a dedicated software.

Every flat includes also a map with the flat's position and I need to render it via Google Maps.

The flats (query) are updated every night. There are more than 120 flat that are daily updated.

So far everything fine, Google Maps works properly, but I realized that the costs of the Google Cloud Platform are increasing, drastically.

There is a way I can limit this? I only need to display in front-end (and back-end) the position of the available flats.

Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: it is not completely clear which APIs you are using. By "update" of the flat do you mean that you do a geocode-search for the address to get lat/lng? This could be cached in your database. If you mean the Google Maps impressions, you can use the static images API if this suits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Maps API for free within your first 90 days of registration. After that, you are billed proportionally to how many requests are sent. You will probably use the Static Maps API if you are just going to load the flat's location. [Here is more pricing information.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/usage-and-billing)